# How to extract column labels as column comments for Hive from sas7bdat files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, sas

I'm using [saurfang/spark-sas7bdat](https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat) library to convert sas7bdat files to csv.

How to extract column labels as column comments for Hive?

I went through the documentation, it says to set extractLabel parameter to True.
But it did not work for me.

Comment: can you show what you tried ?

Comment: You could try getting that information using `dsread` from http://www.oview.co.uk/dsread (disclaimer: I am the author of `dsread`).

Comment: Thank you Chris, I'll try using dsread.

Comment: Hi Steven, I'm trying to set extractLabel parameter to True while reading the file, and saving the dataframe as a hive table.                                                                                      df = spark.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load(path, forceLowercaseNames=True, inferLong=True, extractLabel=True)                               
                                                                                              
df.saveAsTable('db.table')